# Unable to resolve TS2802 Type Map<> can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to resolve this issue with no luck. I searched the different articles regarding the **downlevelIteration** and the **target** and modified both tsconfig.json and package.json, but still I get the same error message.

My tsconfig.json is as follows

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        // NZ 2022-09-09
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "lib": ["DOM","ES6","ES2015.Collection","ES2015.Iterable"],
        //--------------
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "composite": true
    }
}
```

Part of the source code that defines the **Map** structure is as follows:

```
interface outBrk {
title: string;
subTitle: string;
...


type fldName = string;
const fields = new Map<fldName, keyof outBrk>([
        ['Title', 'title'],
        ['Sub-title', 'sub_title'],
        ...
```

and the code that triggers the error msg is

```
for (const [xlsxKey, jsonKey] of fields) {
        if (jsonKey) {
            if (jsonKey === 'vlnlist') {
               ...
```

and the error msg is

```
error TS2802: Type 'Map<string, keyof outBrk>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.

248     for (const [xlsxKey, jsonKey] of fields) {
                                         ~~~~~~
```

I would like some guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it your editor that is lacking?

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: @kelly I get this error msg when I execute the tsc command inside the VS Code terminal

Comment: Weird part is that `es6` is the same as `es2015`, according to docs. Could it be that you have another `tsconfig.json` with different `target` which is closer (from folder hierarchy PoV) to your code?

Comment: @alx is right. There's something else going on here. ES6 is just an outdated Alias for ES2015 because TC39 changed their versioning convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had same error, setting `tsconfig.json` from CommonJS to ES modules with target, module, `moduleResolution` helped me.

my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
}
```

Comment: If that's how you fixed it then there's a bug that's been introduced recently, a very weird bug. The target module format has nothing to do with iterator support. This definitely has nothing to do with module resolution I'll tell you that